# div with text over another, no over with IE8

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, textblock

I have two div, the left align with the right one. I need the left block to go over the right. As you know IE is still the problem ... The text in the two blocks is mixed, no over is processed, the text seems indepdendent.

The jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/P3Qgb/

Here the code :

```
<html>
    <style>
            #root {
                position:fixed;
            }

        #content {
          height: 200px;
          width: 400px;
          border: 1px solid red;    
          position:fixed;
        }    

        #bloc-left {
                position:absolute;
                float: left;
                height: 190px;
                border: 1px solid black;
                width: 60%;
                overflow:auto;

                background-image: linear-gradient(top, #fbfbfb 0%, #e2e2e2 100%);
                background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #fbfbfb 0%, #e2e2e2 100%);
                background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #fbfbfb 0%, #e2e2e2 100%);
                background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #fbfbfb 0%, #e2e2e2 100%);
                background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #fbfbfb 0%, #e2e2e2 100%);
                background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0, #fbfbfb), color-stop(1, #e2e2e2));
        }

        #bloc-right {
                float: right;
                width: 45%;
                height 190px;
                border: 1px solid black;
        }    
    </style>

    <body>
            <div id=""root">
            <div id="content">
             <div id="bloc-left">
              Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
             </div>
          <div id="bloc-right">
              Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting 
          </div>
      </div>
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

The goal is to add a link which expand the left block over the right, with some js.

Thanks for your help !

EDIT: add root div

Answer (score 0):

add:

`z-index: 1;` to `#bloc-left`

change:

`position: fixed;` to `position: relative;` on `#content`

Comment: Not working :/ I Forgot to say #content is in a div positioned to fixe, and i can't update it

Comment: Problem fixed. IE8 doesn't support background-image:linear-gradient, so i put a simple background-color and it's working